# Sumar las columnas de un archivo txt en python según su código

Tags: python, archivo

Tengo un archivo de 80 registros, cada registro tiene 6 columnas ordenadas de la siguiente forma:

NOMBRE CODIGO DATO1 DATO2 DATO3 DATO4

El problema pide sumar las columnas DATO1, DATO2, DATO3 y DATO4 POR SEPARADO dependiendo del código, es decir, sumar las columnas de los registros que tengan el mismo código (0,1,2,3...9) e imprimirlos al final. Cada vez que el código cambie debería imprimir la suma de cada columna.

Una restricción del problema es que no se debe usar arreglos.
Intenté usando un ciclo while, almacenando el código en una variable y comparándola pero no me arroja nada.

Editado: Dejo código, el problema es más largo y al hacer el ciclo while creo que estoy creando un bucle infinito y por eso no me arroja nada, está mal pero de todas formas lo pongo.

```
archivo=open('datos_py.txt','r')
def promedio(d1,d2,d3,d4):
    prom=(d1+d2+d3+d4)//4
    return prom

def clasificacion(prom):
    if prom>20:
        print('a')
    elif prom<=20 and prom>= 15:
        print('b')
    elif prom<=14 and prom>=10:
        print('c')
    else:
        print('d')

for linea in archivo:
    nombre=linea[0:4]
    codigo,dato1,dato2,dato3,dato4=map(int,linea[5:].split())
    suma_dato1=0
    suma_dato2=0
    suma_dato3=0
    suma_dato4=0
    n=0
    while codigo<codigo+1:
        suma_dato1+=dato1
        suma_dato2+=dato2
        suma_dato3+=dato3
        suma_dato4+=dato4
        n+=1
    print(nombre)
    print(promedio(dato1,dato2,dato3,dato4))
    prom=promedio(dato1,dato2,dato3,dato4)
    clasificacion(prom)
archivo.close()
```

Adjunto parte del archivo

```
BTLF 0 18 19 2 3
UIYP 0 11 1 19 23
KMUK 0 24 17 4 7
YTYY 0 8 9 7 3
ZKED 0 14 9 8 0
TNUM 0 1 5 15 7
SLGW 0 18 18 7 6
VRQX 0 2 0 21 19
NZEN 1 18 2 19 18
LSVD 1 15 9 16 16
KHPI 1 20 23 10 25
MPWT 1 3 23 12 18
NPZP 1 7 14 4 8
ENAL 1 7 9 21 14
KSEF 1 12 19 13 17
BXIP 1 5 3 22 9
NQLH 2 22 18 22 7
GWSQ 2 11 21 14 25
HRAR 2 25 3 2 15
RKPN 2 19 11 17 21
HDCQ 2 11 2 25 10
LIYE 2 3 18 17 0
VIDG 2 22 22 0 1
QMJD 2 15 21 21 18
AHUT 3 16 18 15 19
PBCN 3 2 14 9 17
ICJW 3 22 16 0 21
OWNL 3 3 20 12 7
TAEO 3 12 7 7 20
WANP 3 14 10 8 3
ZXNP 3 6 7 10 3
ZAVC 3 4 10 2 25
DNEM 4 1 15 21 19
OOSG 4 25 8 17 21
EGKW 4 0 5 21 14
OXYU 4 3 16 0 13
IZJK 4 15 17 19 15
YCKN 4 7 2 10 2
YYFR 4 4 7 22 20
NIUL 4 16 7 23 19
OPCF 5 21 15 6 14
WXLB 5 6 5 1 15
VBXT 5 22 8 13 5
OZOW 5 5 4 10 23
MHEA 5 15 9 24 13
YQIY 5 25 12 17 20
WOXM 5 16 16 11 15
GOVW 5 13 23 5 5
WMHY 6 7 2 6 21
VYYH 6 23 0 19 11
KRZB 6 16 7 16 9
QMHK 6 18 23 10 13
YZIL 6 2 18 8 7
YMKB 6 1 3 3 12
GZNJ 6 7 19 21 14
JXFL 6 9 6 24 17
PVZG 7 16 9 3 10
MIBQ 7 2 8 24 8
RSVI 7 6 0 2 0
GKHS 7 7 21 3 18
ELRA 7 1 1 16 23
GPMC 7 4 7 9 11
IMYX 7 2 5 21 22
EBTM 7 19 4 24 0
LDQC 8 9 18 10 18
YPLN 8 22 8 16 4
MFIO 8 7 24 20 17
TUMG 8 13 13 19 20
ZWLP 8 8 20 20 14
FHEM 8 20 24 20 14
OAAB 8 13 25 2 11
YKYU 8 7 9 24 8
PLHM 9 25 5 17 21
PQJZ 9 11 11 3 1
EXSE 9 12 21 20 7
PYBE 9 3 19 14 10
DMCU 9 6 4 17 25
ZGCB 9 23 9 23 5
ALWK 9 10 13 8 1
GRYX 9 5 13 10 15
```

Comment: Nos podrías muestras lo que has intentado? Código?

Comment: Tu bucle `while codigo<codigo+1` nunca dejará de ejecutarse. Porque codigo+1 siempre será mayor a codigo. No has pensado reemplazar `codigo` por `n`, `n` nunca se usa y mi solucion seria:`while n<codigo+1:`.

Comment: Lo intenté pero en cada línea el contador vuelve al inicio del while y prácticamente no suma nada

Comment: Tampoco usas las variables: `suma_datos1....4`. Cambiando codigo por n:`while n<codigo+1` me funciona bien. Pero como te digo: Para que son las variables `suma_datos1...4`.

Comment: Es un acumulador de los datos1...4, se supone que debería sumar cada columna respectivamente hasta que el código cambie de 0 a 1 y así sucesivamente, si el código cambia (suma los 8 registros) debería imprimir el acumulador. Ya usé el while con el n pero no acumula nada, me podrías mostrar cómo lo hiciste? por favor

Comment: print(suma_dato1....4); ¿Eso es lo que te refieres?. ¿Y porque no usas un if en ves de un while?. Por ejemplo: `if codigo==0:` Se suma los acumuladores.

Comment: Ya No, entiendo.

Comment: Con el if lo suma pero hasta fin de archivo y sólo funciona para un caso. Yo tampoco entendí muy bien que digamos xd

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123384/discussion-between-daniel-briceno-and-synth-man).